# Saving cropped Uploadcare image with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, uploadcare

Having a bit of a head scratcher with [Uploadcare's](https://uploadcare.com) Widget in PHP when it comes to cropping.

The widget is cropping, but uploading a full size image regardless. Grabbing the UUID and storing it in database for later retrieval.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

As per the PHP API I am passing the attributes in the array

```
getInputTag('uuid', array("data-images-only" => "true", "data-crop" => "150x150"))
```

Controller code

```
$uuid = $api->getFile($request->uuid)->data['original_file_url'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Uploadcare always uploads original files.
When user crops an image in the widget, it returns a CDN URL with [cropping operations](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/cdn/#operation-crop) applied.

You need to capture this URL (not just UUID) and save it in your app.

This may help:

`$cropped_url = $api->getFile($request->uuid)->getUrl();`

Also note, that `uuid` is a misleading input and var name in this case :)